# Vue.js and Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, vue.js

is there a way to import timeline of a certain group from facebook to my website?
I could manage it by embedding posts and just dynamically assign a URL, but it would require adding a line of code for every single post.

How can I import all the current posts and automatically add new posts from facebook to the website?
Using Vue.js

Comment: There are no plugins for a group feed, you’d have to read the posts yourself via API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/group/feed

Comment: @CBroe there’s a way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-facebook-page but it works a bit dodgy.